# How to run commands after SSHpass without closing connection?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, kvm

I'm learning how to use Linux, and want to see if I can run a set of commands after using **SSHpass** into a machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
clear
virsh start rhel8.4-2server
sleep 10
sshpass -p "PASSWORD_HERE" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no server@IP_ADDRESS_HERE
echo "Hello and good day" && date
```

This will ssh into the machine just fine, but it doesn't execute the **echo** and **date** command. Those commands run only after the connection has been closed.

[image]

---

I found another thread talking about using EOF, but as I read more into this. This closes the connection after the commands are run. But I want the connection to remain open instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
clear
virsh start rhel8.4-2server
sleep 10
sshpass -p "PASSWORD_HERE" ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no server@IP_ADDRESS_HERE << EOF
echo "Hello and good day" && date
EOF
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `-t` flag (allocate psuedo-terminal) for the `ssh` command, and then specifying your commands followed by `; /bin/bash`.

Example:

```
[root@server1 ~]# sshpass -p 'hunter2' ssh -t bubba@server2 'date; /bin/bash'
Thu Sep 30 22:24:32 EDT 2021
[bubba@server2 ~]$
```